# How to make a marker with a svg in the center

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, mapbox

I am trying to make markers on my map like this on my ReactJs map, but I am not sure how to make the external marker thing.

[image]

Here's the the best I can do with css. However, it's not close to a marker but I am not sure how to change it. Any help is appreciated

[image]

```
import * as React from "react";
import ReactCountryFlag from "react-country-flag";
import FlagIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Flag";

const wrapperStyles = {
  aspectRatio: "4/3",
  background: "mist",
  overflow: "hidden",
  display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "center",
  alignItems: "center",
  borderRadius: "20%",
};

function Pin({ country }: CountryFlagPinProps) {
  return (
      <div style={wrapperStyles}>
        <ReactCountryFlag
          countryCode={countryCode}
          svg
          style={{
            width: "2em",
            height: "2em",
          }}
        />
      </div>
  );
}

export default React.memo(Pin);
```

App.tsx

This is the app.tsx of my code.

```
import React from "react";
import MAP, { Marker } from "react-map-gl";
import Pin from "./Marker/Pin";
export default function MapboxMap(): React.ReactElement {

  const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
    latitude: 22.3027,
    longitude: 114.1772,
    bearing: 0,
    pitch: 0,
  });

  const [mapStyle, setMapStyle] = useState("mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v12");


  return (
    <div style={{ width: "100vw", height: "100vh" }}>
      <MAP
        initialViewState={viewport}
        mapboxAccessToken={process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN}      >

       
          <Marker
            longitude={city.lon}
            latitude={city.lat}>
            <Pin country={city.country} />
          </Marker>
        ))}
      </MAP>
    </div>
  );
}
```